# How to iterate through JSONArray Using RXJava 2?

Tags: android, json, rx-java2

to iterate through array list one can use following code

```
 List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<>();
                        latLngs.add(new LatLng(5,5));

                        Observable.just(latLngs)
                                .concatMap(array -> Observable.fromIterable(array))
                                .subscribe(v-> Log.d(TAG, "subscribeToTopic: "+v.latitude));
```

but how to iterate through JSONarray like this using Rxjava?

```
 [{
    "vehicleId": "5c11e863a361762fdbe99fae",
    "latitude": "19.952829",
    "latitudeDir": "N",
    "longitude": "73.735054",
    "longitudeDir": "E",
    "speed": "0.0",
    "ignition": "0",
    "batteryStatus": "1"
 }, {
    "vehicleId": "5c11e863a361762fdbe99fae",
    "latitude": "19.952829",
    "latitudeDir": "N",
    "longitude": "73.735054",
    "longitudeDir": "E",
    "speed": "0.0",
    "ignition": "0",
    "batteryStatus": "1"
 }, {
    "vehicleId": "5c11e863a361762fdbe99fae",
    "latitude": "19.952829",
    "latitudeDir": "N",
    "longitude": "73.735054",
    "longitudeDir": "E",
    "speed": "0.0",
    "ignition": "0",
    "batteryStatus": "1"
 }, {
    "vehicleId": "5c11e863a361762fdbe99fae",
    "latitude": "19.952829",
    "latitudeDir": "N",
    "longitude": "73.735054",
    "longitudeDir": "E",
    "speed": "0.0",
    "ignition": "0",
    "batteryStatus": "1"
 }]
```

Comment: why are you iterating a collection with Rx when you could in this case just use a regular `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JSONArray implements the List interface (assuming that you using simplejson here), you can pretty much do the same:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
Observable.fromIterable(jsonArray)
  .subscribe(e -> {
    System.out.println((JSONObject) e);
  });
```

EDIT: based on your comments i think you're not using simplejson but this org.json.JSONArray which does not implement the List interface. In this case you can iterate like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
Observable.range(0,jsonArray.length())
  .map(jsonArray::get)
  .subscribe(e -> {
     System.out.println((JSONObject) e);
  });
```

Comment: gives error... i have already tried this. fromIterable
(java.lang.Iterable<? extends T>)
in Observable cannot be applied
to
(org.json.JSONArray)

Comment: i also tried right now, it seems to work for me. Can you share some additional info, what versions are you using from rx and from simplejson. and what is the exact error message?